# EditText: show input window, retrieve text, and change its height

Tags: android, android-layout

In my project, I have a list of products available in table-layout. 
I need two things

1. When the user click on `EditText` numeric keypad should display below it.
2. After user enter numeric value, how we can get the entered Edited text box value.?

I have `EditText` like this:

```
 EditText txtQty = new EditText(this);
 txtQty.setTextSize(2, 12);
 txtQty.setHeight(4);
 txtQty.setWidth(6);
 txtQty.setId(i);
 txtQty.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
 txtQty.setText("0.00");
 tr.addView(txtQty);
```

3. How we can reduce `EditText` box height? I did but it didn't change that much

[image]

Please give me idea...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 events to acheive this. First is onTextChangedListener if you want to get text from EditText each time it is edited. Second is onKeyDownListener. You can check whether the key equals to enter. getText().toString() is used to get the text of EditText. Here is a code snippet:

```
        myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                String tmp = draw.myEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        //to hide keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```